# Why when I try to access to this old WordPress site it is opened the installation page?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am not so into WordPress and I have the following problem.

Some years ago I create this wordpress site for an humanitarian association of a friend. Then I never administrated it for years.

Today my friend call me and say to me that the WordPress site disappeared

So going on the main page:

```
http://www.TEST.com/
```

it show the WordPress installation page. I really have no idea about what could be happen and what who handle this site can have done.

The only idea is that maybe have done the WordPress version update and something went wrong. I have not a recent backup

What can be happen? How can I try to solve this situation and restore the website. Going into the FTP it seems that the file and the theme are here. The only strange thing is that there is the **install.php** installation script into the **admin** folder and I am pretty shoure to have removed after the installation years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The wp-config.php file is probably missing or not set up properly, so the site is not connected to the database.